# Relay mutation does not update my UI

Tags: reactjs, relayjs

I have created this gist that represents my current case.
Basically I have an object with details, in this details I have an item selected from a list. I have different types of list.
And the selection has relation with the user too.

So I am calling a mutation in order to change the selected item, The mutations works as expected, but my UI remains outdate.

https://gist.github.com/dobleuber/c74625704c37d7245b747d31b3c433cc

types.graphql

```
type User @model {
  id
  userObjectSelection: [UserObjectSelection!]!
}

type Object @model {
  id
  name
  userObjectSelection: [UserObjectSelection!]!
  selectionType: SelectionType!
}

type SelectionType @model {
  id
  items: [SelectItem!]!
  objects: [Object!]!
}

type SelectItem @model {
  id
  name
  selectionType: SelectionType!
  userObjectSelection: [UserObjectSelection!]!
}

type UserObjectSelection @model {
  id
  user: User!
  object: Object!
  selectedItem: selectItem
}
```

ObjectPage.js

```
const query = graphql`
  query ObjectPageQuery($objectId: ID!, $userObjectSelectionId: ID!) {
    object: node(id: $objectId) {
      ...Object_object
    }
    selection: node(id: $userObjectSelectionId) {
      ...Object_selection
    }
  }
`;
changeSelectedItem (selectionId, itemId) {
  mutateSelectedItem(selectionId, itemId, () => console.log('updated'));
}

///
render={({ error, props }) => {
    if (error) {
      return <div>{error.message}</div>;
    } else if (props) {
      return (
        <div className="object-page">
          <Item
            object={props.object}
            selection={props.selection}
            onSelectItem={this.changeSelectedItem}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }

    return <div>Loading</div>;
  }}
///
```

Object.js

```
const Object = ({ object, selection, onSelectItem }) => {
  const {id} = object;
  return (
    <div>
      <span>{id}</span>
      <div className="item-list">
         object.selectionType.items.edges.map(({ node }) => (
              <Item
                key={node.__id}
                item={node}
                userObjectSelectionId={selection.id}
                onSelectCard={onSelectItem}
                selectedItem={selection.item}
              />
            ))
      </div>      
    </div>);
};

createFragmentContainer(Object, graphql`
  fragment Object_story on Object {
    details
    selectionType {
      id
      items: {
        edges: {
          node {
            ...Item_item
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  fragment Object_selection on UserObjectSelection {
    id
    selectedItem: item {
      ...Item_selectedCard
    }
  }
`);
```

mutation.js

```
const mutation = graphql`
  mutation UpdateUserObjectSelectionMutation($input: UpdateUserObjectSelectionInput!) {
    updateUserObjectSelection(input: $input) {
      UserObjectSelection {
        id
      }
      SelectItem {
        id
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: If you mutate the state, how React can figure out that components should be rerendered with new props?

Comment: relay wraps the components with an store, and yep, that store is sent to the components by props

Comment: Can you show your mutation implementation too? Also, as far as looking at your schema, your code seems to not following the relay specification. If you intend to use connection, PaginationContainer is required or if you just want list of items, there should be no `edges` and `node` nests.

Comment: Yes I am using relation, but I omitted a lot of things to post the question. let me add the mutation

Answer (score 1):

After to check the code and debug the mutation and update code in relay, I found what the error was in my mutation result.
I was returning the incorrect 'selectItem'.

I updated my mutation.js and it's working properly right now.

```
const mutation = graphql`
  mutation UpdateUserObjectSelectionMutation($input: UpdateUserObjectSelectionInput!) {
    updateUserObjectSelection(input: $input) {
      UserObjectSelection {
        id
        SelectItem {
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```